# Python How to do an while statement with multiple tries then loop

Tags: python

Python - I am trying to get some code to check whether a webpage has loaded correctly, and handle a couple of exception (but not error) scenarios.

So the code would do the following

```
While the webpage is not loaded correctly (I have set some variables to control this)
    try to check whether the page had loaded correctly
    try to check whether it hasn't loaded correctly as the account is logged out
    try to check whether it hasn't loaded correctly as it needs an update
    otherwise wait 5 seconds and loop through the block again, until the maximum number of retries has been hit
```

I tried doing Try, except, except but as the errors are not specific (TypeError etc) then I get an 'Only one catch all' code rejection

I also considered an If Elif etc but then I don't know how to get it to loop back to the start if it doesn't match any of the scenarios and needs to wait and then try again.

The code I have tried

```
while not loaded and attempts < maxattempts and not loggedout: #confirm that the page is not loaded, not too many attempts or logged out.
try:
    x1, y1=pygu.center(pygu.locateOnScreen("/whatsappopened.png", confidence=0.8))
    time.sleep(2)
    pygu.moveTo(x1,y1)
    current_time = now.strftime("%H-%M-%S")
    loaded =True
except:
    x1, y1=pygu.center(pygu.locateOnScreen("whatsapploggedout.png", confidence=0.8))
    time.sleep(2)
    pygu.moveTo(x1,y1)
    loggedout =True
except:
    x1, y1=pygu.center(pygu.locateOnScreen("/whatsappupdate.png", confidence=0.8))
    time.sleep(2)
    pygu.hotkey('ctrl', 'w')
    loggedout =True
except:
    time.sleep(5)
    attempts += +1
    print("page not loaded after %s attempts" %(attempts))
```

Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: @AidanDonnelly added - although I know it is wrong.

Comment: Can you include your imports and variable initialisation also?

Comment: Also, as you stated, you may only use one try except without catching the exact exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a potential solution with comments that may let you think about how to continue with the program and suit it to your needs.

```
attempts = 1
maxattempts = 5
loaded = False
loggedout = False
update = False

time_now = datetime.now()

while not loaded and attempts < maxattempts and not loggedout: #confirm that the page is not loaded, not too many attempts or logged out.
    # Check if WhatsApp is open
    try:
        x1, y1=pygu.center(pygu.locateOnScreen("whatsappopened.png", confidence=0.8))
        print("WhatsApp opened")
        time.sleep(2)
        pygu.moveTo(x1, y1)
        time_now = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        loaded = True
    except Exception as e:
        # Here because WhatsApp is not open or logged out
        # Check if WhatsApp is logged out
        try:
            x2, y2=pygu.center(pygu.locateOnScreen("whatsapploggedout.png", confidence=0.8))
            print("WhatsApp logged out")
            time.sleep(2)
            pygu.moveTo(x2, y2)
            loggedout = True

        except Exception as e:
            # Check if needs update
            try:
                x3, y3=pygu.center(pygu.locateOnScreen("whatsappupdate.png", confidence=0.8))
                print("WhatsApp update")
                time.sleep(2)
                pygu.moveTo(x3, y3)
                update = True
            except Exception as e:
                # Not open
                print("WhatsApp not open")
                time.sleep(2)
                attempts += 1
                time_now = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                loaded = False
                loggedout = False
                update = False
    print("Attempts: " + str(attempts))
```

Comment: That worked a treat. Thanks for that. Really appreciated.